# C# .NET: How to design a template and multiply it in a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, templates

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to say:

[image]

You can see in the picture that I want to make a template and multiply it in my application. I came up with an idea that put the controls in a panel and multiply the panel with code, but the constructor of the panel wouldn't allow me to do that. Is there any other way I can multiply it cause I can't drag and drop all the controls into the form?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `UserControl` and draw your Template inside the `UserControl`.

Then on the MainForm, you can use a `LayoutPanel` and dynamically instantiate your `UserControl` and add it to the `Controls` Collection of the `LayoutPanel`.

**Step1**
Create a new UserControl(say ucTemplate), and add the picture box & labels in it.

**Step2**
In the Main Form:
Add a new LayoutPanel(or a simple Panel.

And whenever you want to repeat your template, simply call the `addTemplate()` method.

```
Public sub addTemplate()
    Dim ucTemplate = new ucTemplate()
    ucTemplate.Dock = Dock.Top

    LayoutPanel1.Controls.add(ucTemplate)
End sub
```